# How to derive to places past the decimal in Ruby or Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, decimal

I am trying to make a currency value.

```
>> 100.00
```

I tried this:

```
irb(main):021:0> 100.number_to_currency
NoMethodError: undefined method `number_to_currency' for 100:Fixnum
    from (irb):21
```

I tried this :

```
irb(main):021:0> 100 * 1000.round.to_f/1000
=> 100.0
```

Any ideas? Rails3 + Ruby 1.8.7

Comment: Were you using Rails console, as opposed to IRB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`number_to_currency` is a Rails helper method - it's not an instance method of Fixnum.  In Rails 2.3.8, at least, you can do:

```
number_to_currency(100)
```

Although you might need:

```
number_to_currency(100, :precision => 2)
```

To get the right number of decimal places.  You can change the default, and a bunch more display options, by editing your I18n translation files.

Or, if you just want a quickie that you can run easily from the console, too:

```
sprintf('%.02f', 100)
```